# Concerning ShowLegend in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, legending

I found a code for [Mie Scattering from 2007](http://diogenes.iwt.uni-bremen.de/vt/laser/codes/Mie%20Code%20-%20Lompado-new.zip), written for Mathematica.

I have edited it quite a bit, since there are package definitions that we don't need, etc.

But I am having difficulties figuring out why the plot with ShowLegends does not work.

The command is

```
CLegend = {{{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(scat\)]\)"}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(abs\)]\)"}, {RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
 "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(ext\)]\)"}}, 
LegendPosition -> {-.55, 0.3}, LegendSize -> {0.25, 0.25}, 
LegendShadow -> {0, 0}};

ShowLegend[
Show[CScatPlot, CAbsPlot, CExtPlot, 
DisplayFunction -> Identity], DisplayFunction, 
CLegend -> $DisplayFunction ]
```

It only outputs this with no legends present.
[image: ShowLegends]
[image: showleg]

Comment: Did you load the legend package ``Needs["PlotLegends`"]``?

Comment: I don't think I need to? I have Mathematica 9.0 where it's not required?

Comment: @l3win You are using old functions from the `PlotLegends` package, which xslittlegrass mentioned. If you want to use v9 functions, you'll have to translate them yourself to use the newer ones. Did you try loading it first to see what happens? (ignore the warning)

Comment: rm I just loaded the command. See my original post. I am not sure, I think I don't have to change the LegendSize, LegendPosition or LegendShadow. Does it have to do with RBGColor etc.?

Comment: The whole `DisplayFunction` maneuvering that the code is doing is very pre version 6. [cont...]

Comment: [cont...] The way plots are generated and combined changed considerably in v6. Specifically, the plot output itself used to be a side effect of the function and it needed to be suppressed by `DisplayFunction -> Identity` if all one wanted was to store the plot for later combination with other plots. With versions 6 and higher, the plot became the main effect of the plot function and it can be directly combined with other plots in a `Show` or assigned to variables without generating unwanted extra plots. A `;` suppresses graphics output just like it does for numerical output.

Answer (score 8):

The package `` PlotLegends` `` is obsolete in v9, and so is the package `` Graphics`Legend` `` that the Mie code notebook was using. Since you are running v9, you might as well use the new stuff which is integrated much better. Of course, as there are several plots to combine, the method is going to look similar, but not as convoluted as the old form.  The high level object which represents a legend is `Legended`, and it can be used as follows:

```
Legended[ graphics object, Placed[legend]]
```

In this case, the graphics object is generated by `Show`, but note there is no need to supply `DisplayFunction -> Identity` to it anymore. The legend specification is also fairly straightforward, and I felt [`LineLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LineLegend.html) was the most appropriate.

```
Legended[
  Show[CScatPlot, CAbsPlot, CExtPlot], 
  Placed[
   LineLegend[
    {Red, Blue, Black}, 
    {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(scat\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(abs\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(ext\)]\)"}
   ], 
   Right
  ]
]
```

[image]

You will have to alter each plot by hand, but it seems all of the legend specifications in the notebook have the same form:

```
{{{color, label} ..}, options}
```

So, we can easily create a conversion function:

```
Clear[ToNewLegend]
ToNewLegend[{spec_, ___}, pos_:Right, opts:OptionsPattern[LineLegend]] := 
  Placed[LineLegend[##, opts], pos]& @@ Transpose[spec]
```

When applied to `CLegend` from the notebook, we get

```
ToNewLegend[CLegend]
```

[image]

This simplifies the conversion to

```
Legended[
  Show[CScatPlot, CAbsPlot, CExtPlot],
  ToNewLegend[CLegend]
]
```

with the possibility of changing positions of the legend or supplying alternative options to it, as desired.